# REGEXP_SUBSTR QUERY

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Anyone can explain why below query return different result?

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('123 Maple Avenue', '[[:alpha:]]+') ADDRESS FROM DUAL;
```

Result: Maple

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('123 Maple Avenue', '[:alpha:]+') ADDRESS FROM DUAL;
```

Result: apl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first query, you're using the POSIX character class `[:alpha:]`, which matches alphanumeric characters.

In your second query, you're matching against the *literal* characters ":alpha:", which matches only a, p and l in your example string.